# Casting XAML to XML in Visual Studio

Tags: xml, wpf, visual-studio, powershell, xaml

I am trying to cast XAML code to XML code for a WPF project in Visual Studio so I can more easily use with PowerShell. But I am getting the below error.

Code:

```
[xml]$XAML = "@
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Controler"
    Title="Ahmad's PowerShell Utitlity" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="36*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="430*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="51*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Header="Actions" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="285" Margin="18,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <GroupBox Header="Computer Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="73,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <GroupBox Header="Results" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="203" Margin="73,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="258" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Margin="0,46,375.756,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Button Content="Services"/>
        <Button Content="Process"/>
        <Button Content="Drives" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</Window>
"@
```

> Errors:
>   Error                      The token "[xml]$XAML = "@   " is unexpected.
>   Error                      'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.' XML is not valid.
>   Severity               Code     Description         Project File         Line        Suppression State
>   Error                      Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'Controler' that could not be found. 
>   Severity               Code     Description         Project File         Line        Suppression State
>   Error                      The token "   "@" is unexpected.

Comment: Did you [walk through this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/08/01/ive-got-a-powershell-secret-adding-a-gui-to-scripts/)?

Comment: [PowerTip: Use Here-Strings with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/31/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/): `[xml]$XAML = @"` instead of `[xml]$XAML = "@`

Answer (score 0):

As JosefZ clearly stated, the way you have taken the XML is wrong.

Instead of `[xml]$XAML = "@`

Do This: `[xml]$XAML = @"`

Then you can access the nodes like `$XAML.Window`